# Looking for Diode L V 108 datasheet

Tags: diodes

What is this diode and what is it used for?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According the [marking](https://www.vishay.com/docs/88912/diodesgroupbodymarking.pdf), it is a [SMBJ20A](https://www.vishay.com/docs/88392/smbj.pdf), a [Transient Voltage Suppressor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transient_voltage_suppressor) (TVS).